# Microsoft graph API access problem when create online meeting or online meeting event

Tags: azure, api, graph, microsoft-live-meeting

I am trying to use "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events" or "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings" to create online meeting programmatically.

I used help from many resources specially this
https://vikrantsdynamicsblogs.wordpress.com/2020/03/28/programmatically-create-the-teams-meeting/.

I have used this API to get token using password grant type
"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token" but the problem happened when I am calling "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings" I got 403 Forbidden

and when I am trying to call "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events" using the same access token I am getting this response

[image: Error message]

I have added delegate permission from Azure portal

[image: Permissions added]

Any Ideas why both are not working with me?

Answer (score 1):

Authorization errors can occur as a result of several different issues, most of which generate a 403 error (with a few exceptions). We could refer to this doc to [resolve Microsoft Graph authorization errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/resolve-auth-errors#steps-to-resolve-common-errors).

We cannot create online meeting via **personal Microsoft account**, if you are using **work or school account**, we need to ensure the account has the permission: `OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite`, if you are create online meeting via **Application**, we need `OnlineMeetings.Read.All` and `OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All*` permission, check this [Create onlineMeeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) and [Online meetings permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#online-meetings-permissions) for more details.